# Calling a derived virtual function

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, vector

I'm still fairly new to C++ and inheritance has gotten me in a pickle.
I know this works in C# since I'm always using Base.();

I'm hoping to be able to call a vector array of PlayerCharacter, derived from Entity.
Currently when I call it, it only calls Entity's update method.

```
int main()
{
vector<Entity*> list;
list.push_back(&PlayerCharacter());

   for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
   {
   list[0]->Update();
   }
}

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(void);
   ~Entity(void);
    int hitpoints;
    virtual void Update(void);
};
void Entity::Update(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    a++;
}
class PlayerCharacter : public Entity
{
public:
    PlayerCharacter(void);
    ~PlayerCharacter(void);
    bool Move();
    void Update() override;
};
void PlayerCharacter::Update(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    a--;
}
```

Comment: To call to the base class (what I think you're asking) use `Entity::Update()` inside of `PlayerCharacter::Update()`.  In c++ a class can have several non-abstract base classes (unlike c#) so you need to explicitly identify the base class to access a base class member.

Comment: Are you *certain* it's `Entity::Update` that being called?

Comment: Oh gawd, you're pushing a pointer to a temporary variable into the vector!  Replace your `push_back` line with: `list.push_back( new PlayerCharacter() );` and remember - you need to `delete` the items in the vector to avoid a memory leak.  also, `list` is a class name in the STL so called the instance of the `vector` something else - might I suggest `vec`.?

Comment: `list.push_back(&PlayerCharacter());` is pushing a pointer to a temporary that immediately gets destroyed so the pointer in the vector is immediately invalid.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but from that code example I don't see how you can tell which method is actually executing. In both cases you are allocating a local variable which you ++ or --, then  immediately discard it. How are you observing the result?

Comment: @harmic Fair question - he uses those lines as somewhere to park a breakpoint.

Answer (score 4):

`list.push_back(&PlayerCharacter());` i think this is undefined behavior in your code.

In your case you should allocate the data on the heap like this: `list.push_back( new PlayerCharacter() );` otherwise if you do this `&PlayerCharacter()` then the PlayerCharacter variable will be destroyed immediately and the pointer inside the list will point to garbage bytes.

Also to track which function is called you can use the debugger or print something in the console from each Update function.

Comment: I do, yes, that's why I have int a = 0; a++; so the debugger runs past that line of code and I can pick it up. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: actually this seems to have fixed it to my surprise! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @user3065340 don't forget to mark the reply to be the answer to your question if it fixed your problem :)

Comment: @user1158692 :) , i think it was calling it because the vtable from the base class was still there, but it could happen anything from a crash to a memory corruption , that's why it's called ub.

Answer (score -1):

This Works :
Few changes though : 1) You dont need to put Override 2) Definition of Constructor and destructor once declared 3) Created object of derived class and passed it to the list.

Output is : Inside PlayerCharacter

If you want to call base class update method method remove the volatile keyword. Or use base class pointer pointing to base class object.

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    ~Entity();
    int hitpoints;
    virtual void Update(void);
};

Entity::Entity()
{
}
Entity::~Entity()
{
}
void Entity::Update(void)
{
    std::cout << " Inside Entity" <<std::endl;
    int a = 0;
    a++;
}
class PlayerCharacter : public Entity
{
public:
    PlayerCharacter();
    ~PlayerCharacter();
    bool Move();
    void Update();
};
void PlayerCharacter::Update(void)
{
    std::cout << " Inside PlayerCharacter" <<std::endl;
    int a = 0;
    a--;
}

PlayerCharacter::PlayerCharacter()
{

}

PlayerCharacter::~PlayerCharacter()
{    

}
int main()
{
    vector<Entity*> list;
    PlayerCharacter ObjPlayerCharacter;
    list.push_back(&ObjPlayerCharacter );

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        list[0]->Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: **Two** comments **and** an answer have pointed out the error the OP made in their `push_back` statement and yet you've replicated it!  I'd advise you to fix it before you get some well deserved downvotes!

Comment: I have created PlayerCharacter Object in main and passign the address of the object to the List. As list expects Entity pointer , so the actually the base class entity pointer is pointing to derived class object PlayerCharacter. Now when we call the update method on list[0] i.e on base class pointer it calls the derived class method due to run time polymorphism.

Comment: @user1158692 - I dont mind your downvotes. It took some time for me to build and run the program meanwhile you guys posted an answer. I would definitely upvote your answer. P.S : Not in a race of getting REPUTATION Points so desperately

Comment: Admittedly, your program **won't** have the same UB issue as the OP's as you're passing the address of a named object and the vector and the object exist in the same scope (in case the OP is reading) - probably not deserving of a downvote.